# Extracting file extension (extname) from Text or String

Tags: haskell

I have a `Text` or `String` containing a filename, say `/foo/bar/foobar.txt`.

How can I defined a function `extname` (similar to [NodeJS's extname](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p), but omitting the leading dot) that only yields the extension (`txt` for the example?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way would be to use [`System.Filepath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.2.1/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:splitExtension):

```
λ> import System.FilePath
λ> snd $ splitExtension "/foo/bar/foobar.txt"
".txt"
```

You can also use `takeExtension` as pointed out by @kosmikus:

```
λ> takeExtension "/foo/bar/foobar.txt"
".txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, you solution seems to be better than mine. I only Hoogled for `extname` but not for `splitExtension`.

Comment: You can also just use `takeExtension`.

Comment: Note, this library is now deprecated.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Thanks for pointing it out, I have update the link to use the `filepath` package which is the replacement for the deprecated system-filepath package.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a basic version of `extname` like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

extname :: Text -> Text
extname = T.reverse . T.takeWhile ((/=) '.') . T.reverse
```

or for `String` (aliased to `FilePath`):

```hs
extname :: FilePath -> FilePath
extname = reverse . takeWhile ((/=) '.') . reverse
```

A possible issue with `extname` is how to handle errors (i.e. what is your definition of *correct* error handling). The functions posted here will, for example, return the whole filename including path if no dot is present in the function.

For example, `extname "/etc/foo.d/config" == "d/config"`.

This specific issue can be resolved by combining `extname` with `basename` (I'll only show the `Text` version from hereon):

```hs
 import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS (fromText, toText)
 import Filesystem.Path (basename)

 extname' = extname . toText . basename . fromText
```

yielding  `extname' "/etc/foo.d/config" == "config"`.

If a leading dot is required (i.e. to mimic the NodeJS behaviour), use:

```hs
 import Data.Monoid (mappend)

 extnameWithDot filename = "." `mappend` extname' filename
```